# Restore the "Hide Ignored Tags" preference to the Interesting Tags box

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, ignored-tags, tag-watching

When the Interesting/Ignored tags feature was first added, the preference to hide questions was in the sidebar.

I liked this, since most of the time I don't mind the questions just being greyed out.. but there are times I want them hidden. Having it enabled all the time seems quite.. destructive (from my view as a user - obviously it doesn't *actually* delete anything)

Current I have to go into my profile, into my settings, click the option and navigate back to the page and reload, just to toggle this..

Seems quite a lot of clicks, especially given that the questions are hidden using Javascript (if I'm not mistaken)..

Comment: Seems like a good thing to write a userscript for...

Comment: Hmm.. Perhaps a javascript bookmarklet might be enough... I'll have a play tomorrow

Comment: Note: It seems like this option now *only* appears in the sidebar (if you click "Edit" in the "Ignored Tags" box), and does not appear anywhere in the settings in the user profile. (I'm not sure whether to tag this as [status-completed], close it as no longer reproducible, or what...) A corresponding feature-request: [Please add the setting for either hiding or graying out questions with ignored tags to the tags preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371901/335251)

Answer (score 5):

That was easier than I thought! Hurray for jQuery.

The following are bookmarklets. Make a new bookmark (in your toolbar), give it a name and change the URL to the `javascript:` code

#### SO/Hide Ignored

Hides any questions with ignored tags.

```
javascript:void($(".question-summary.tagged-ignored").hide())
```

#### SO/Only Interesting

Only shows questions with interesting tags

```
javascript:void($(".question-summary%20+%20:not(.tagged-interesting)").hide())
```

#### SO/Show All

Undoes either of the above

```
javascript:void($(".question-summary").show())
```