# Filtering to display only the questions tagged with an 'interesting' tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)

Hi,

On the 'questions' page, there is the list of the tags I marked 'interesting'. Would it be possible to have the 'Interesting tags' title be a link that would filter the questions so as to display only the questions that have at least one 'interesting' tag?

Thanks.

Comment: You can "Hide Ignored Tags" from your user page - the "Prefs" tab. But I'm guessing that that doesn't go far enough.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions, (you can vote to move this up the list to be worked on).

Comment: +1 for keeping interest up on the idea