# View only "Interesting Tags" questions?

Tags: support, questions, tags, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)
>   [Tab for interesting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)

Is there a quick way of only viewing questions asked which match my interesting tags?

Comment: Short answer: Declined for now, even though the questions have a combined 172 upvotes. Don't expect it any time soon

Comment: Thanks for your response, strange it's not a feature though!