# How can I filter out all questions that don't have an interesting tag?

Tags: support, usability, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)

Is there a way to only view questions that have the tags I consider interesting?

Comment: Related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions).