# Ignore non-favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

I know someone already proposed a filter to [show only favourites tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested). But as explained in one of the answers,

> The reason this cannot ever really be viable is mainly due to caching.
>   If you take a look at how Interesting/Ignored tags are currently implemented, it is actually a very interesting illusion.
>   Every time you refresh, you are getting the same exact page as everyone else. You get a list of questions, and that is pretty much it. All of the interesting/ignored functions are cleverly hidden in Javascript/CSS.
>   On each refresh, the Javascript goes through and marks tags interesting/ignored, and then CSS properly styles them as such.

I personnally don't care(and i'm sure i'm not the only one) about the questions that are not about my favourite tags. **Not at all**. What about a single tag in the ignore section that ignores all the tags that are not in the favourites ?

Something like like

[image]

Right now, correct me if i'm wrong, but the only way of recreating this is by adding every tags (+- 35 000) to the ignore list.

Comment: You can just add "*" as ignored tag.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That would also hit every other tag that's not in your favorites on each question which *is* a favorite.

Comment: @animuson true just noticed that. So feature request asking the favorite tags to take precedence over ignored tag would solve this. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes I will reformulate this. Thanks also I didn't know about the *

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [tag filter on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/filters) that only shows questions with your favorite tags on a site. There is even a default filter that will show you all questions with your favorite tags across the whole network.

This of course means that you have to go to a different site, so it is not as convenient. And unfortunately the tag filters don't have the nice live refresh for new posts yet.

Comment: Thats a nice work around that I could look into. But I must admit i'd love not to have to change website.