# Favourite tags to take precedence over * tag

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

As proposed in [my previous question about ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177490/ignore-non-favourite-tags) :

Let's say I want to ignore all tags except my favourites, so I add `*` to the ignored tags. The problem is that this will truly ignore all questions, including those that contain my favourite tags.

I suggest we change it so that favourite tags can take precedence over the `*` symbol in the ignored section.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, as Hannele observes, `*` by itself is not a very useful filter to use on favorites (and I may even block it). I'm thinking in my head of various ways of implementing it, but I can't help thinking that it is simpler just to use the existing multi-tag functionality, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xna%20or%20winforms%20or%20c%23%20or%20sql-server-2008%20or%20sql%20or%20vb.net%20or%20tsql%20or%20.net

(which is readily bookmarked etc)

We could perhaps make it easier to get to just your favorites, for example at `/questions/favorite`. However, I don't think that what we're discussing here should be implemented by hacking the `*` as a filter - if anything, we should remove the ability to enter `*` as a favorite / ignored tag.

Comment: Your're right. And, the `/Questions/favourite` should be implemented.

Comment: I realised eventually that `*` is more useful as a wildcard in conjunction with another tag (for example, `php*` to turn up everything regarding PHP, regardless of a specific version). However, perhaps it still shouldn't be allowed all on its lonesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think my [previous suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59660/133217) of merging the two separate `Favorite Tags` and `Ignored Tags` lists into one single list would be a solution for your request. Each element then has the property of either interesting or ignore and the order of the elements gives priority, with the highest matching item "winning".

You could then have

- favourite-tag-1: interesting
- favourite-tag-2: interesting
- ...
- favourite-tag-N: interesting
- *: ignore