# Please add the setting for either hiding or graying out questions with ignored tags to the tags preferences page

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, preferences

On different sites, I have different settings enabled for ignored tags. For instance, on Mi Yodeya I have for some reason had it set to hide questions with ignored tags for the past several years. This shows up at the bottom of the homepage because of that:

[image: Hiding questions because of your Ignored Tags preferences for tags: purim-torah-in-jest]

The link on "Ignored Tags preferences" takes you to /users/tag-notifications/current.

However, that page does not have on it anywhere the setting for graying out or hiding ignored tags.

[image: Ignored tags, Mi Yodeya: Add a tag | purim-torah-in-jest]

The only place that I can find to change this setting is in the ignored tags box on the homepage:

[image: Ignored tags list on homepage with selections for "Hide questions in your ignored tags" and "Gray out questions in your ignored tags"]

Can this setting please be placed on the tags preferences page, especially since it's linked there? I lost ten minutes searching for the setting because it wasn't in the place that the link indicated it would be.

Comment: Not to mention that a switch that only appears when the box is clicked on has relatively poor discoverability.  (Especially since you don't need to use that box to add or cancel ignored tags, so you may not normally interact with it at all.)